# How should I branch out two work items, one is enhancing master, the other is enhancing the first one?

Tags: git, branch, pull-request, branching-and-merging

Just to clarify:

- Master contains some stuff already
- Work Item #1 (from now on: "#1") enhances master (fixes some stuff, adds methods...)
- Work Item #2 (... "#2") uses some of the methods introduced by #1 and adds more stuff

I've done both things overnight :D

I am wondering how to branch out in such a way that the reviewer can merge things incrementally? I don't want to plop both work items in one pull-request, that would be a whopper to review!

From my "local working" point of view, it makes sense to branch out of Master once for #1 and then branch out of #1 to add the stuff for #2... However, the reviewer will have to collapse this in the reverse order, right? They'll have to merge #2 into #1 and then #1 into Master... But they can't merge #2 into #1, from an ethical point of view, because they don't know what #1 does yet!

I don't really know how git works in real scenarios. I understand the commands but how people use them (more specifically, how they expect me to use them) - that's the tricky bit for me!

One idea I have: I still do it that way and then they just need to read and approve both in chronological order, first... And then merge in the "collapsing" order (#2->#1->Master)?

Or: They can merge #1 into master, and since #2 is "relative" to #1, it will "follow" #1 and, once #1 is merged, #2 will be immediately merge-able into master?

At this point I might add that the reviewer knows even less git than me... I don't have anyone to ask, really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will do the right thing.

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
 \        ^     ^
  m       |     |
  ^       |     |
  master  #1    #2
```

If you merge #1 into master (or create a pull-request/merge-request for your reviewer to review), then only the changes from commits `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` will need to be reviewed. Once `#1` is merged to `master`, the pull-request/merge-request of `#2` to `master` will only contain the changes of `g`, `h`, and `i` to review.

There is no problem of a "double merge" of the changes, because Git already knows that `b` through `f` have been merged into the master branch and only `g` through `i` are new.

Visually, performing the merge of `#1` to `master` first and then `#2` to `master` second, will result in:

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
 \        ^\    ^\
  m---------n-----o
  ^       |     | ^
          #1    #2|
                  master
```

`n` being the merge result of merging `#1` into `master` (`git checkout master && git merge '#1'`) and `o` being the merge result of merging `#2` into the updated `master` already containing `#1` (`git checkout master && git merge '#2'`)

Comment: I was more fearing that once #1 is merged, #2 might be lost, as it's a "child" of a merged branch?... Does it matter if I opt to "close branch after merging" for #1 or not?

Comment: @DraxDomax no, this assumption is not correct. The important thing in Git are the commits. Each commit points to one or more parent commits. A normal commit points to a single parent, a merge commit to two or more parents. Commits will nevre be deleted, as long as they are _reachable_, i.e. being pointed to by another commit or by a ref (such as a branch or tag). Branches are nothing more than cheap labels. They can be created, deleted, and moved at any time. They do not affect any of the commits. When you merge, you merge commits, not branches. Branches are just helpful names for head commits